# Node server connection to MySQL gets lost

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, amazon-rds

Connection to **AWS RDS** gets lost frequently without emitting any error events like `PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST` etc while using pool connections. When API server gets a request, instead of error mysql returns empty array as the result.

I can see the the connection dropped in the RDS dashboard but **no error event was emitted**.
I have tried the solutions like changing the `mysql_connections_options` like `connectTimeout`, `wait_timeout` etc , plus I have also tried pinging mysql server at short regular intervals (Which returns the correct result) but still the connection gets lost and the query return empty array as the result without any error.

Here is my connection code:

```
connection = mysql.createPool(mysqlConnectionOptions);
function pingSqlServerForPersistentConnection() {
    console.log("PINGING : ");
    connection.getConnection(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('MYSQL ERROR CONNECTION : ' + err);

            pingSqlServerForPersistentConnection();
        }
        else {
            if (config.get("APP_NAME") == "prod") {
                setInterval(selectStar, 150000);
            }
            console.log('Connection established');
        }
    });
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("MYSQL DISCONNECTED : ", JSON.stringify(err));
        pingSqlServerForPersistentConnection();
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.log("MYSQL : \n PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST");
            pingSqlServerForPersistentConnection();
        }
        if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
            console.log("MYSQL : ETIMEDOUT");
            pingSqlServerForPersistentConnection();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you get in console?

Comment: On starting the server, connection to mysql is successful so i get ""Connection established".After sometimes when the connection to mysql is lost , all query returns empty array and no error until i restart my api server

Comment: Do you get **MYSQL DISCONNECTED** in console?

Comment: NO , As i mentioned i recieve no event from mysql , so the code block for error handling mysql events is never executed